# Why are the upvote and downvote buttons visible on a user's own post?

Tags: feature-request, design, voting, user-interface

I saw, when I posted a question on Stack Exchange/Stack Overflow, there are upvote and downvote buttons for our post. But we can't upvote nor downvote the post. Why didn't Stack Exchange remove it for our own posts?

Any reason why they didn't make the upvote button viewable for other users only? Not the user who posted the question/answer?

Comment: It was asked ini 2010... 7 years later... Hmm okay..

Comment: If it makes you feel better, asked in 2009, 2010....

Comment: My bad.. i thought they Will change the feature after a couple of years later...

Comment: Reasons for good design decision don't change.  As for getting the same feature request a second look, then submit an answer, to the duplicate (provided it's not closed)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably because it's simpler to design a page that would render the same way *until* you clicked on it, rather than having different, not quite consistent designs for a page depending on whether it's your post or not.

Once you click on it, there are interaction and feedback, and it can tell you you aren't allowed to vote for yourself in a fairly consistent manner.